# help me remove this additional parameter in url

Tags: urls, parameter

One of my websites is having an additional parameter `/?v=e5477cbee260` after the url. I do not understand what is this and how to remove it.I am using a godaddy hosted website .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by woocommerce.

Woocommerce has a setting called **Geolocate (with page caching support)** which adds this parameter to every your url.

The said option can be found in your dashboard at:

**Woocommerce → Settings → General → Default Customer Location**

Selecting any option apart from **Geolocate (with page caching support)** should resolve the issue

Comment: You can tick the answer as correct and upvote it:)